# Заказчик просит логотип в кривых, а это изначально не обсуждалось

Tags: вектор, photoshop

Заказчик просит логотип в кривых, а это изначально не обсуждалось. Изначально было как: я написала, что выполню логотип и пришлю работу в форматах png, jpeg и psd. Назвала сумму за работу. Работа выполнена, заказчик утвердил логотип и пишет, что ему нужно в кривых логотип. Я пишу, что о кривых изначально речи не было, речь шла о форматах png, jpeg и psd. В этих форматах я и отправила работу. Изначальная договоренность выполнена. Кто прав?

Comment: наверное, это неправильное место для такого вопроса. Но конечно, вы

Comment: Вы на каком сайте заказ получили?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что этот сайт не про отношения заказчик/исполнитель.

Comment: Логотип в кривых можно предоставить в формате psd. Никакого противоречия тут нет. Другое дело, что этот вопрос видимо не обговаривался

Comment: почему psd - это в кривых? так можно в eps или corel втянуть растр и тоже сказать, что это вектор :))